# Указание JS скрипта в HTML

Tags: javascript

Что это за запись подключения JS?

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="$js=exports"></script>
```

И по какой логике это работает?

Comment: Самый обыкновенный тег script, который описывается в абсолютно любом учебнике по html.Только адрес у скрипта какой-то странный, но почему он такой, спрашивайте у того кто вписал этот адрес, а не у нас

Comment: это шаблонизатор

Comment: посмотрите, как собирается этот `html`, явно вы привели не конечный результат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего это строка из какого-нибудь шаблонизатора, и к клиенту она в таком виде не попадет. То есть строка `$js=exports` замениться на нормальный путь к файлу.

Конечно можно создать на сервере файл `$js=exports`, доступный по адресу `https://example.com/$js=exports`. Это допустимое имя файла, но так называть файл ни кто в здравом уме не станет.

Comment: Да, действительно шаблонизатор. Сбило с толку. Спасибо.